# How to simply encrypt and decrypt cookie string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, encryption, cookies

I am trying to encrypt a string when setting it as a cookie with javascript AES, it encrypts fine. but after I recuperate the string (within the cookie) to decrypt it, it doesn't come back as the original string.

```
class Auth{
    constructor(){
        this.pass = "iscae";
        this.cookies = new Cookies();
        this.email = this.cookies.get("email");
        this.connected = false;
        this.checkConnection();
        return this;
    }
    checkConnection(){
        if(this.email !== undefined){
            this.email = crypto.AES.decrypt(this.email,this.pass).toString();
            this.connected = true;
        }
        else{
            this.connected = false;
        }
        return {
            email : this.email,
            connected : this.connected
        };
    }
    connect(email){
        this.email = crypto.AES.encrypt(email,this.pass).toString();
        this.cookies.set("email",this.email);
        return this;
    }
    disconnect(){
        this.cookies.remove("email");
        return this;
    }
}


export default Auth;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in the line:

```
this.email = crypto.AES.decrypt(email,this.pass).toString();
```

Without a parameter in `toString()` you'll get a string of hexadecimal ASCII codes.
For example, when the plain text is "test@email.com", you'll get:

> 7465737440656d61696c2e636f6d

in hexadecimal representation (74="t", 65="e",...).

To get the normal string representation, i.e.

> test@email.com

you need to pass a parameter like this:

```
toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
```

`toString` behaves like this because the decryption function `crypto.AES.decrypt()`returns a byte array, as the content could be binary data as well (e.g. pictures or other data). `toString()` just converts each byte into it's hexadecimal string reprensentation.

By passing the parameter `CryptoJS.enc.Utf8` you tell the `toString()` method explicitely to treat the bytes as UTF-8 encoded characters.

Comment: thank you! its really not straight forward when i google this stuff, yet the solution was so simple. thanks to you and stackoverflow, god bless.